# augtool shows only /etc and /boot

Tags: augeas

By default augtool can only see the following directories

```
/etc  
/boot
```

Root is set to /.

```
[root@]# augtool ls /files
etc/ = (none)
boot/ = (none)
root/ = (none)
```

Can't find nothing about it in errors:

```
[root@]# augtool print /augeas//error (all messages concerns /etc)
```

How can I make Augeas see other directories?

Comment: Have an issue here too, anyone get past this?  This is over a year old, any other way to bump it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require a lens that will filter a path you need.

One hack I did was to modify a filter I wanted (i.e. the xml.aug ) and added the following

```
 . (incl "/usr/tomcat/apache*/conf/*.xml")
```

This goes at the end where you have a **let filter** command already.  The end is now

```
let filter = (incl "/etc/xml/*.xml")
    . (incl "/etc/xml/catalog")
    . (incl "/usr/tomcat/apache*/conf/*.xml")

let xfm = transform lns filter
```

This will find all xml files in my apache conf directory and make them editable.  Appears you'll have to do something simmilar, though I didn't find a best practice for this.

Answer (score 1):

By defaults, Augeas tries to parse all the files it knows about. Most of these configuration files are located in `/etc` (and sub-directories, just try looking *inside* `/files/etc`). `/boot` is essentially for Grub configuration files.

If you do a `print /files`, you'll probably see the contents of a few hundred files.